# How to secure same inheritance hierarchies e.g. for MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, hierarchy

I´ve got a base ViewController and a base ViewModel. The base ViewModel is used by the base ViewController. Also, I´ve got 2 subclasses of ViewControllers and 2 subclasses of ViewModels that need to be used together.

Example:

```
class BaseViewModel {
    func somethingBasic() {}
}

class ConcreteViewModel1: BaseViewModel {
    func somethingConcrete1() {}
}

class ConcreteViewModel2: BaseViewModel {
    func somethingConcrete2() {}
}

class BaseViewController {
    let viewModel: BaseViewModel

    init(with viewModel: BaseViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

class ConcreteViewController1: BaseViewController {
    init(with viewModel: ConcreteViewModel1) {
        super.init(with: viewModel)
    }

    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete1() //this does not work
    }
}

class ConcreteViewController2: BaseViewController {
    init(with viewModel: ConcreteViewModel2) {
        super.init(with: viewModel)
    }

    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete2() //this does not work
    }
}
```

The question is: what is the preferred solution to make `viewmodel.somethingConcrete1()` and `viewmodel.somethingConcrete2()` work?

Comment: you should use protocols or implement `somethingConcrete2` in base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed this with a few other colleagues, and we came around with this solution, based on **`Composition`** instead of inheritance:

```
class BaseViewModel {
    func somethingBasic() {}
}

class ConcreteViewModel1 {
    private let baseViewModel = BaseViewModel()
    func somethingConcrete1() {}

    func somethingBasic() {
        baseViewModel.somethingBasic()
    }
}

class ConcreteViewModel2 {
    private let baseViewModel = BaseViewModel()
    func somethingConcrete2() {}

    func somethingBasic() {
        baseViewModel.somethingBasic()
    }
}

class BaseViewController {}

class ConcreteViewController1 {
    private let base = BaseViewController()
    private let viewModel: ConcreteViewModel1

    init(with viewModel: ConcreteViewModel1) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete1()
    }
}

class ConcreteViewController2: BaseViewController {
    private let base = BaseViewController()
    private let viewModel: ConcreteViewModel2

    init(with viewModel: ConcreteViewModel2) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete2()
    }
}
```

With that solution, you get the type safety, you avoid Generics and you don´t need to cast anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Try using **`Generics`** for this.

Create `init` in `BaseViewController` accepting a *generic parameter* `T` constrained to type `BaseViewModel`, i.e.

```
class BaseViewController<T: BaseViewModel> {
    let viewModel: T

    init(with viewModel: T) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Now inherit `ConcreteViewController1` and `ConcreteViewController2` from `BaseViewController` giving the specific type for *generic parameter* `T`, i.e.

```
class ConcreteViewController1: BaseViewController<ConcreteViewModel1> {
    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete1()
    }
}

class ConcreteViewController2: BaseViewController<ConcreteViewModel2> {
    func useViewModel() {
        viewModel.somethingBasic()
        viewModel.somethingConcrete2()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but is it good in terms of architecture? I mean MVVM

Comment: That´s what I did, it looked good in the beginning. But after the project startet to grow, it got pretty messy. Here´s a class signature when using this: https://pasteboard.co/IqOwJ0m.png

Comment: @stk image not found

Comment: @Erumaru in plain text: 
`open class BaseDetailViewController<ItemType, ItemViewModelType, ViewModelType: BaseDetailViewModel<ItemType, ItemViewModelType>, CellType: BaseDetailCell<ItemType, ItemViewModelType>, HeaderViewType: BaseDetailHeaderView, FooterBarType: DetailFooterBarView>: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, SharingAlertProvider, Deselecting, DismissImageDetail {`

Comment: Well, like I mentioned: your solution is good, but I wanted to find an alternative. I found something and I´ll post it here